# The probability of any particular value of a continuous distribution occurring is zero

Tags: statistics

The probability of any particular value of a continuous distribution occurring is zero

So I totally understand why this is true mathematically. However, say $x$ is a continuous random variable and $P(x)$ is its probability distribution. Say we run our experiment and observe a value of $x=x_k$. Then $x_k$ just occurred, and yet $P(x=x_k)=0$. How can an event with a 0 probability of occurring, occur?

Looking for more of an intuitive explanation rather than for someone to explain how integration works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written "Say we run our experiment and observe a value of $x=x_k$"

Ask yourself, to what degree of accuracy can you say $x=x_k$?

A continuous random variable can never take an exact value, only a value which is rounded to a certain degree of accuracy, so the actual value must lie in an interval. The single value cannot be assigned a probability, but the interval can be, using integration of course.

This is my intuitive understanding of why, even though a given value may appear to have occurred, the probability of that single value occurring is zero.

Comment: This is what I needed to hear. Thank you sir.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Take a solid cylindrical bar of uniform radius and uniform density.  If you pick an arbitrary point in the bar, the *weight* of the disk through that point perpendicular to the axis of the bar is zero.  You only get weight if you have a slab of nonzero thickness (i.e., you integrate an interval of positive length).

Comment: This is probably a good as answer as there is. That being said, the fact that an event occurred that technically has a 0% chance of occurring still annoys me a bit.

Comment: @NumToez : It is possible that you are conflating *a priori* probability with *a posteriori* certainty.

Answer (score 0):

Events with probability $0$ are *not impossible*. In a similar fashion, events with probability $1$ are not necessary to happen.

I always use the following example. Think of throwing a needle onto a line segment. Say the point on the very left of the segment corresponds to
$0$, the one on the right to $1$, the one in the middle to $\frac 12$, and so on. Assume the needle is equally likely to hit any point on the segment.

Now throw the needle. Assume it hits, say, $x_0=0.43242...$. What's the probability of this outcome occurring? Well, if it was non-zero, say $p>0$, then so would be the probability of the needle hitting $\frac 12$, $\frac 13$, $\frac 14$, and so on (by the assumption that the needle is equally likely to hit any point on the segment).

But then the probability of the needle hitting one among $\frac 12$, $\frac 13$, $\frac 14$, ... would be $\mathbb P(\text{needle hits }\frac 12)+\mathbb P(\text{needle hits } \frac 13)+\mathbb P(\text{needle hits } \frac 14)+\cdots=c+c+c+\dots=\infty\cdot c=\infty$, which is absurd, as probabilities are bounded by $1$.

The only unambiguous assumption that we made was that $p>0$. Hence $\mathbb P(\text{needle hits } x_0)=0$, even though we just witnessed the event's occurrence.